# RecyclerView Layout file throws the exception: Failed to find view with ID ...:id/recyclerView in item layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I'm currently trying to implement my first ever RecyclerView in Xamarin.Android.

In my main layout file, i have a DrawerLayout which contains a FrameLayout and a ListView. What i am trying to achieve is that each time an item from the ListView is clicked, a Fragment containing a RecyclerView will be loaded using the FragmentManager.

The issue i face is that each time i return from OnCreateView in the Fragment, i get the above exception.

What confuses me most is that when i step through the code in OnCreateView, FindViewById does not throw an exception and seems to populate recyclerView correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

DiscoverNew.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

DiscoverNewFragment.cs

```
public class DiscoverNewFragment : Fragment
    {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        IngredientsAdapter ingredientsAdapter;
        List<Ingredients> listOfIngredients;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DiscoverNew, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView;
            var layoutMan = new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context, 2, GridLayoutManager.Vertical, false);
            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutMan);
            listOfIngredients = IngredientsData.LoadIngredients(this.Activity);
            ingredientsAdapter = new IngredientsAdapter(listOfIngredients);
            recyclerView.SetAdapter(ingredientsAdapter);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.cs

```
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        . . . 
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
             . . .
            OnMenuItemClick(0);  // Load Fragment 0 at startup    
        }    
        . . .    
        void OnMenuItemClick(int position)
        {         
            base.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.frameLayout, new DiscoverNewFragment()).Commit();
            this.Title = "Discover";
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(drawerListView);    
        }
    }
```

NB: i have omitted some code from MainActivity.cs which is related to the setting up of the drawer layout

Comment: Did you try a different cast like `recyclerView =  view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);` ?

Comment: @FabriBertani Thanks for your suggestion. I've just given this a try and unfortunately the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just resolved this issue by reverting the following nuget package from version 27.0.2.1 to version 26.1.0.1:- xamarin.android.support.design
I know it's more of a work around than a solution but after trying different things, this was the only option that seemed to work.